# Maven dependency with MySQL

Tags: maven, dependencies

I need to specify the MySQL database with the help of Maven 2. In the dependency, what kind of groupID and artifactID shall I use?

How can one find groupID and artifactID`s for different products? That is, I don't know those for MySQL, or they are not important? How does it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main Maven repository is located at repo.maven.apache.org. You can search it (for packages) at the site http://search.maven.org. A search for [mysql](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|mysql) turns up the mysql-java-connector, which is probably what you want. The groupid and artifactid are listed on the search page.

Comment: One issue I can mention as addition do this answer is to recommend adding such artifacts with `<scope>runtime</scope>`. This is probably less known Maven scope and I don't see it used even with dependencies such as JDBC driver or JSTL taglib or JPA vendor (with pure use of JPA) that fit perfectly into `runtime` scope.